# How to check if ansible playbook failed inside Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, return-value

Below is my Jenkins pipeline script. I wish to call ex("ansible-failed") function whenever the ansible-playbook test.yml fails.

Below is my pipeline script.

```
def ex(param)
    {
    echo "ABORT due to:" + param
    }

pipeline
    {
    stages
        {
        stage('first')
            {
            steps
                {
                script
                    {
                    def user = "user1"
                    }
                echo "Calling ansible"
                ansiblePlaybook(
                        playbook: '/app/test.yml'
                        extraVars: [ app_ip: "10.0.0.12,10.0.0.13" ]
                                )
                }
            }
        stage('second')
            {
            steps
                {
                script
                    {
                    println "Second Play"
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The above Jenkins pipeline script invokes ansible-playbook test.yml however, I do not know how to detect if the ansible play succeeded or failed. If it failed; then I wish to call the ex() function.

Incase ansible-playbook run succeeds then I wish to simply continue and execute stage('second')

Can you please suggest how we can check the condition if ansible run succeeded or failed inside the Jenkins pipeline script?

Answer (score -2):

You can use try{}catch(){} for that